# C# exception for accessing same resources two times

Tags: c#-3.0

Using Windows Forms and calling the WordNet API in a button click handler:

```
frmWordnetAPI relatedWords = new frmWordnetAPI ();
        relatedWords.ShowDialog();
```

this API is getting some data from the source file directory.

When compiling the program, on the first button click the form is loading perfectly, but when I close the API and click the button again to load it is throwing an exception saying:

```
The process cannot access the file 'D:\MIT\project\wordnet API\TestApplication\WNdb-3.0\dict\index.adj' because it is being used by another process.
```

The following code is throwing an exception:

```
BinarySearchTextStream searchStream = new BinarySearchTextStream(indexPath, new BinarySearchTextStream.SearchComparisonDelegate(delegate(string searchWord, string currentLine)
                        {
                            // if we landed on the header text, search further down
                            if (currentLine[0] == ' ')
                                return 1;

                            string currentWord = currentLine.Substring(0, currentLine.IndexOf(' '));
                            return searchWord.CompareTo(currentWord);

                        }));
```

Please help!

Comment: try throwing a using() block around your definitation of searchStream.

It looks like you're using a word dictionary library, and it probably wants exclusive locks on the dictionary file. See if there is an option to allow multiple reads, or ensure that you are properly disposing your resources (which will free up any locks).

Comment: can pls give me some example for use using statement then i can check with my one ... thanx for ur kind help

Comment: using(BinarySearchTextStream searchStream = new ...)
{
  

}

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered with what you presented here. No one knows what is "BinarySearchTextStream" and what it does(at least google says nothing about it). I can give you only general advice - close your streams, use using(...){} and don't open files with exclusive flag (eg. FileShare.None).

Comment: hi thanx for help 
this is code of BinarySearchTextStream

  public class BinarySearchTextStream : SearchTextStream
    {
        public BinarySearchTextStream(Stream stream, BinarySearchTextStream.SearchComparisonDelegate searchComparison);
        public BinarySearchTextStream(string path, BinarySearchTextStream.SearchComparisonDelegate searchComparison);

        public override string Search(string key, long start, long end);

        public delegate int SearchComparisonDelegate(string key, string currentLine);
    }

pls help thanx

Comment: This is not code, but method signatures generated from metadata - this doesn't change anything. Did you try to close this BinarySearchTextStream or use using statement with it?

Comment: yep i want help .. i tried it early .. after that i upload the question :(

Comment: can pls give me some example for use using statement then i can check with my one ... thanx for ur kind help

Comment: Look at how streams are used here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

Comment: I can't help you any further if I don't see the code. Check the documentation of your library for examples of usage and if you're doing everything correct then consider reporting a bug to the creator.